# Selectively consume messages based on message body attributes in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

Let's say I have a situation where I need to wait for up to 1 minute for some action to be performed.

If it is expired, then try different action.

My current solution proposal is based on RabbitMQ features.

I would create following resources:

```
@Bean
DirectExchange exchangeDirect() {
    return new DirectExchange("exchange.direct");
}

@Bean
Queue bufferQueue() {
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
    args.put("x-message-ttl", amqpProperties.getTimeToLive().toMillis());
    args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", "exchange.direct");
    args.put("x-dead-letter-routing-key", "timedOutQueue");
    return new Queue("buffer.queue", true, false, false, args);
}

@Bean
Queue timedOutQueue() {
    return new Queue("timed.out.queue", true);
}

@Bean
Binding bufferQueueToExchangeDirect() {
    return bind(bufferQueue())
            .to(exchangeDirect())
            .with("buffer.queue");
}

@Bean
Binding timedOutQueueToExchangeDirect() {
    return bind(timedOutQueue())
            .to(exchangeDirect())
            .with("timed.out.queue");
}
```

When I add action to `bufferQueue` and I don't receive any delivery update within 1 minute, this request is then moved to `timedOutQueue` thanks to `bufferQueue's` TTL.

I can attach application rabbit listener to `timedOutQueue` and use different action.

When I add action to `bufferQueue` and I receive confirmation that action was successfully performed, I'd like to remove given action event from `bufferQueue`.

I couldn't find such feature in RabbitMQ, i.e. being able to receive selectively.

I also found some articles saying that selective consuming is antipattern.

Is it possible to selectively consume messages from RabbitMQ queue?

What is proper way to implement this pattern in RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no concept of message selection in RabbitMQ.

The "proper" way for an application that wants to selectively receive messages is to use multiple queues/routing keys with a consumer on each specific queue he expresses interest in.

However, there is no way to "remove" a message from the middle of a queue; only the head.

> When I add action to bufferQueue and I receive confirmation that action was successfully performed, I'd like to remove given action event from bufferQueue.

That makes no sense to me; when the message timed out in `bufferQueue` due to TTL, and was moved to `timedOutQueue`, it no longer exists in `bufferQueue` so there is nothing to remove.

There is also no mechanism to ...

> and I don't receive any delivery update within 1 minute,

... because each message in a queue is independent.

It doesn't sound like your application is suitable for a message broker at all.

Comment: There are 2 cases:
either event times out in `bufferQueue` and it is automatically moved to `timedOutQueue`
or event is supposed to be removed from `bufferQueue` because I received some confirmation before timeout was reached. I want to remove it from the `bufferQueue` because otherwise event would time out and it would be processed by `timedOutQueue`'s subscriber

Comment: I receive confirmation / delivery update to separate queue from different application, so I know when the action was already performed

Comment: >`I want to remove it from the bufferQueue ...` There is simply no way to "remove" arbitrary messages from a queue without consuming them (and all of those ahead of it). You "could" do it by consuming and not acknowledging those ahead of it, acking the one you want to remove and then reject and requeue all the others but that is not at all efficient.

Comment: I prototyped the solution where instead of `bufferQueue` I use `org.springframework.amqp.core.AnonymousQueue` with a name containing unique id I can rely on, `x-message-ttl`, `x-dead-letter-exchange` and `x-dead-letter-routing-key` = `timedOutQueue`. I delete this `AnonymousQueue` when I receive confirmation for given unique id before timeout is reached. So I selectively delete queues instead of selectively consuming messages. Are there any drawbacks to this approach?

Comment: My understanding from your original question was that `bufferQueue` would contain many "event"s and you wanted to selectively delete one of them. Your prototype description sounds much different to that. So I really don't understand your use case. Maybe you can reword the question to make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, my original question was related to 2 queues - `bufferQueue` and `timedOutQueue`. I changed my solution based on your answer that it's impossible to consume selectively. Instead of `buffer` queue, I have now many temporary anonymous queues and `timedOutQueue`.

Comment: OK. However, `AnonymousQueue` will create an auto-delete queue, which will disappear if you lose the connection. You may want to make a normal durable `Queue` that will survive network glitches. You can still use the `Base64UrlNamingStrategy` to give the Queue a unique name.